# How to convert PDF to CGImage and then save to a high DPI JPG image?

Tags: macos, pdf, cgimage

I know there is a way to save the PDF pages to `NSImage` and then output to JPG like this:

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToUrPDF];    
NSPDFImageRep *pdfImg = [NSPDFImageRep imageRepWithData:pdfData];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSInteger pageCount = [pdfImg pageCount];
for(int i = 0 ; i < pageCount ; i++) {
    [pdfImg setCurrentPage:i];
    NSImage *temp = [[NSImage alloc] init];
    [temp addRepresentation:pdfImg];
    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[temp TIFFRepresentation]];
    NSData *finalData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];
    NSString *pageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%ld.jpg", (long)[pdfImg currentPage]];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", @"pathWrUWantToSave", pageName] contents:finalData attributes:nil];
}
```

However the "`TIFFRepresetation`" can only output as 72 DPI highest. So I think the best way to get the high DPI image from a PDF is using `CGImage` on Mac OS X. How to do this? My destination application is for Mac OS X, not iOS...

Thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got the solution:

Since OS X 10.8, NSImage has a block based initialiser to draw vector based content into a bitmap.
The idea is to provide a drawing handler that is called whenever a representation of the image is requested.
The relation between points and pixels is expressed by passing a NSSize (in points) to the initialiser and to explicitly set the pixel dimensions for the representation:

```
NSString* localDocuments = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfPath = [localDocuments stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.pdf"];
NSData* pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPath];
NSPDFImageRep* pdfImageRep = [NSPDFImageRep imageRepWithData:pdfData];
CGFloat factor = 300/72;
NSInteger pageCount = [pdfImageRep pageCount];
for(int i = 0 ; i < pageCount ; i++) {
    [pdfImageRep setCurrentPage:i];
    NSImage* scaledImage = [NSImage imageWithSize:pdfImageRep.size flipped:NO drawingHandler:^BOOL(NSRect dstRect) {
        [pdfImageRep drawInRect:dstRect];
        return YES;
    }];
    NSImageRep* scaledImageRep = [[scaledImage representations] firstObject];
    /*
     * The sizes of the PDF Image Rep and the [NSImage  imageWithSize: drawingHandler:]-context
     * are define in terms of points.
     * By explicitly setting the size of the scaled representation in in Pixels, you 
     * define the relation between ponts & pixels.
     */
    scaledImageRep.pixelsWide = pdfImageRep.size.width * factor;
    scaledImageRep.pixelsHigh = pdfImageRep.size.height * factor;
    NSBitmapImageRep* pngImageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[scaledImage TIFFRepresentation]];
    NSData* finalData = [pngImageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];
    NSString* pageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%ld.jpg", (long)[pdfImageRep currentPage]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", pdfPath, pageName] contents:finalData attributes:nil];
}
```

Comment: I use PDFs to manage resolution independent images, which than are scaled to fit whatever size needed. Drawing in block had the very nice side effect of speeding up considerable the PDF raster, yosemite.